# How to disable INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P in gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to disable `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` during run time. Somehow

```
if(condition)
  INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(DISABLE_TEST, xxx)  // disable
else 
  INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(TEST, xxx)         // do not disable
```

Comment: what's wrong with the pseudocode you've shown?

Comment: I think you can use command line switches to filter which test (don't) execute. But it probably should be done before RUN_ALL_TESTS().

Comment: Also, you can provide your own parameter generator, which will generate needed parameters or none. Or you can use `ValuesIn(container)` with corresponding container.

Comment: @JohnFilleau `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` macro must be used in global scope, not in function scope.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen what would you suggest?

Comment: @haruwa I don't have any ideas other than what sklott proposed. Not sure why you want to do that in the first place? What's the point of disabling tests at runtime?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen its just a hack fix. Once a new feature (fix) is complete I will bring the test back.